# Ubuntu Software Center is unaccessible

Tags: 12.04, software-center

When I open Ubuntu Software Center, it appears for sometime with a stopped loading circle and closes automatically. I have been trying to install Google Chrome but as Ubuntu software center is unaccessible.

This is the error when I'm running Software Center from Terminal:

```
2013-09-19 19:24:44,982 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-09-19 19:24:44,987 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-09-19 19:24:45,407 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-09-19 19:24:45,549 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-09-19 19:24:46,194 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 243, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 145, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/glug.nith.ac.in_ubuntu_archives_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2013-09-19 19:24:47,141 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1422, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1352, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 154, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 171, in init_view
    self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 238, in __init__
    self.build(desktopdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 511, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 271, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 450, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 439, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 124, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 317, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 212, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Comment: Could you start from a terminal `software-center` (please note that is written with -ter, not -tre) copy the complete output, *[edit]* your question and paste the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the software center would be the easy solution:

```
sudo apt-get install --purge --reinstall software-center
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Software center is now also unaccessible.

Comment: We can't help you further until you post the error messages produced from running `software-center` in the terminal.

Comment: Hey Joren I'm trying to reinstall this is the output:Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/glug.nith.ac.in_ubuntu_archives_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.